# How to define a repeating function in a Javascript prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, settimeout

I'm trying to define a Javascript *class* with a repeating function but I can't get it to work:

```
var Repeater = function() {
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};

Repeater.prototype = {
    run: 0, // how many runs
    interval: 5, // seconds

    init: function() {
        this.repeat();
    },

    repeat: function() {
        console.log(++this.run);
        setTimeout(this.repeat, this.interval * 1000);
    }
};

var repeater = new Repeater();
```

How should this be done?

Comment: Do you really mean to have all instances share `run` and `interval`?

Comment: @Ian I'm using it as a singleton, but your point is valid

Comment: If it's meant as a singleton, why are you using a constructor approach? I feel like a simple function would suffice

Comment: If it matters, here's how I'd set it up: http://jsfiddle.net/BcaYy/ . I'm obviously not sure how this is being used, but that's how I interpreted it

Comment: @Ian thank you, this was just an example; in reality I have a lot of other stuff going on, which I left out for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var Repeater = function() {
    this.run = 0;  // how many runs
    this.interval = 5; // seconds
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};

Repeater.prototype.init = function() {
    this.repeat();
}

Repeater.prototype.repeat = function() {
    var _this = this;
    console.log(++this.run);
    setTimeout(function () { _this.repeat() }, this.interval * 1000);
};

var repeater = new Repeater();
```

I've moved run and interval into constructor, because if you add this to prototype then this will be spread over all instances.

Your problem lies into `seTimeout` - in your code this timer set new scope for `repeater` and `this` was no longer pointing to `Repeater` instance but for `Timeout` instance. You need to cache `this` (I've called this cache `_this`) and call it into new function passed to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like that:

```
var Repeater = function() {
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};

Repeater.prototype = {
    run: 0, // how many runs
    interval: 5, // seconds

    init: function() {
        this.repeat();
    },

    repeat: function() {
        console.log(++this.run);
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {that.repeat()}, this.interval * 1000);
    }
};

var repeater = new Repeater();
```

You can read more on how `this` behaves in this question : [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: How is that any different than what the OP has done? (you're missing parentheses after that.repeat() )

Comment: @Adam That value of `this` inside of `setTimeout` is not what you expect. Setting `var that = this;` before it and using that will ensure it's referring to the right object.

Comment: I see that it works, but I think you should elaborate your answer. this.repeat inside setTimeout does indeed call the correct function, but it does not call it with the correct scope. setTimeout executes it's function parameter in the global scope, which is what was happening here. Thanks for helping me understand this!

Comment: `but I think you should elaborate your answer` - I completely agree. Code-only answers don't really help

Comment: I've added a link to another question explaining it, because I feel `this` is widely misunderstood, and actually I would duplicate answers  given in that other question. Otherwise I agree with both of you - I should have elaborated in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your repeat function to use a closure in the setTimeout call like so:

```
repeat: function() {
var ctx = this;
    console.log(++this.run);
    setTimeout(function(){ctx.repeat()}, this.interval * 1000);
}
```

You need to set the context explicitly in these kinds of scenarios- that's what the ctx variable is for